# View referred to in a T-SQL Stored Procedure has a red squiggly line under it

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception, view, ssms

I am modifying a stored procedure.
In a WHERE clause of a SELECT, I substituted a view for a table.
Now my viewname has a red squiggly line under it.
The cursor indicates 'Invalid Object Name'.
The name, however is correct and I created the view.
The stored procedure compiles correctly.
What is the problem?
I get an exception when the code that calls the sproc runs (don't know why yet).

Comment: What exception do you get when the sproc runs?

Comment: A procedure will compile fine when an object referenced doesn't exist. This is known as deferred name resolution. Without the actual exception there is little anybody can do. The actual code would be a HUGE help too.